# How to get the value of a grandchild in an expression in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I am building a helper method that takes a model expression and does something with its value, as in:

`Html.EditorFor(expression)`

(that I can use as: `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)`

I've implemented such method as:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyMethod<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    TModel dataModel = html.ViewData.Model;
    MemberExpression mexp = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    PropertyInfo pinfo = mexp.Member as PropertyInfo;
    string currentValue = dataModel != null ? pinfo.GetValue(dataModel) as string : null; //exception on this line
    [do something with the value...]
}
```

This works for getting values of direct children of the model such as `model.Name`, but for higher degree references, trying to get a value such as `model.SomeChild.Name` is throwing an exception:

`Object does not match target type.`

After some investigation, it turns out that member expression is referencing `SomeChild`, where the property info holds info on `Name`. When I try to get the value, it tries to get `model.Name` in that sense, and crashes.

How do I get the value of grandchildren using expressions in C#?

Comment: If you're just trying to get the actual value, is there any reason you're taking an expression rather than a `Func<TModel, TProperty>`? You can compile an expression to a delegate, of course - although I don't know performance implications around doing that a lot.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'd also need to retain the full expression with member/property names to generate the HTML so that I can and bind the values back to my model on postback. it will be used as an ASP.NET MVC component and I'd like to keep the `Html.XFor(m => m.Property)` convention.

Comment: And does the rest of that work when you've actually got `Html.XFor(m => m.Foo.Bar)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet no it doesn't. I'm trying to achieve that.

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to replace all the current functionality? That sounds like a big job... and you may well find that there are assumptions all over the place that there's a single identifier in the path.

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe not *all* of it as it really is a big job, but at least, I'll be creating a modular method that would fit most of the regular use cases. (I'm not replacing the existing ones, I'm just adding some custom methods that works with our custom models for some special types of fields (e.g an editor for a google place, or for a phone number that has some corner cases that I can't otherwise go with the regular built in approach)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Name` in `model.SomeChild.Name` is not a property of your model class. There is no such thing as a nested property. `Name` is a property get operation on the object returned by the `SomeChild` get operation. It's a bit like `get_Name(get_SomeChild(model))` or `model.get_SomeChild().get_Name()` (pseudo-code).

In your code you would need to recursively unpack the `MemberExpressions` and build up a string from them.

Comment: oh, I'd need to traverse the expression tree recursively then?

Comment: Yes. Make the C# compiler generate you a tree and inspect it in the debugger. The visualization is terrible but you can make out the structure.

Comment: okay, I'll be diving into that. I thought there might be a more robust/built-in way, but apparently there isn't.